# SonarQube “Class not found: javax.xml.rpc.handler.MessageContext” during maven sonar build

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Using sonar cube Version 4.5.2.
Apache Maven 3.0.2
Java version: 1.8.0_65

My maven build process comes up with several errors such as

> Class not found: javax.xml.rpc.handler.MessageContext

How to fix this problem? where is Sonar trying to find this package?

Comment: The current SonarQube version is 6.4, with 6.5 in RC, and the current LTS is 5.6.6. You're going to have a hard time finding help for versions older than that.

Answer (score 3):

you need to add `jaxrpc-api` to resolve this issue. you can fine dependecy below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxrpc-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>
```

you can also use `javax.xml.rpc` to resolve this issue. you can find dependency below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.xml.rpc</artifactId>
    <version>3.0-b74b</version>
</dependency>
```